# Using a background image on h3 class (WordPress)

Tags: css, background-image

Here is an image of the effect I'm trying to get:

[image]

Here is the actual image I've got:

[image]

Here is the site http://ratest10.com/?page_id=2

I tried this;

```
.widget-container {
margin: 0 0 18px 0;
background: #FFFFFF;
width:204px;
padding: 0 8px;
overflow:visible;
}
.widget-title {
color: #222;
font-weight: bold;
background: url(images/sidbar-title-bak.png);
width:240px; height: 45px;
}
```

and then tried mucking around with variations including overflow:visible, and changing the html structure to a div with a class holding the h3, and just didn't get anywhere.

This is a WordPress site and the html is...

```
<li id="categories-2" class="widget-container widget_categories"><h3 class="widget-  title">Categories</h3> <ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the container with the white background is not as wide as your h3. However you could move the background positions to bring it into view. For example:

```
.widget-title {
background-position:-19px 0;
}
```

**Edit:**

Actually sorry, I realized you want it out of the white box by looking at your image. This is what you will need to do.

```
.widget-title {
position:absolute;
}

#main .widget-area ul {
background-color:#FFF;
}
```

And then you might need to change the width of your images. They appear to be a bit long now. Or you could use the background position like I stated earlier.

Comment: I think I got (close to) a cure:

        `.widget-container {
 margin: 0 0 18px 0;
 background: #FFFFFF;
 width:220px;
}
.widget-title {
 color: #fff;
 font-weight: bold;
 background: url(images/sidbar-title-bak.png) no-repeat;
 width:240px; height:45px;
margin-left:-26px;
text-align:center;
line-height:30px;
}`